# Handling Aura component visibility in the controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, promises

I have an Aura component on the Account details page that allows the currently logged in user to register the customer associated with that Account. Here is the markup:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" 
                access="global" controller="CustomerPortalAdminController">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:Attribute name='user' type='User[]' />
    <aura:Attribute name='email' type='String' />
    <aura:Attribute name='showSpinner' type='Boolean' default="true" />
    <aura:Attribute name='isFrozen' type='Boolean' default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="canCreateUser" type="Boolean" default="false"
                    description="Indicates if the logged in user has permission to create a user account for the customer."/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText ="Loading..." />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.user)}" >
        <lightning:card >            
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canCreateUser}">
                <div>
                    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="User" aura:id="newUserForm">
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
                            Register User <br/>
                        </div>
                        <Lightning:outputField value="Important: Username should only be different from email address when the customer needs multiple MyAMP logins using the same email address.">"Important: Username should only be different from email address when the customer needs multiple MyAMP logins using the same email address.</Lightning:outputField>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Username" aura:id="newUserUsername"></lightning:inputField>
                        <lightning:button label="Register" onclick="{!c.handleCreateUser}"/>
                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
                </div>
                <br/><br/>
                Important: Username should only be different from email address when the customer needs multiple MyAMP logins using the same email address.
            </aura:if>
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:if>
```

This component is conditionally rendered. Currently, it is displayed only if the user has the required permission set to register customers. The check for this is performed in the `doinit` method of the controller (by calling `c.canEnableExternalUser`):

```js
({
    //Controller function to intilizing the lightning component.
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.getUserDetails(component);
        helper.getIsFrozen(component);
        helper.getEmail(component);
        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);

        var canRegister = component.get("c.canEnableExternalUser");

        canRegister.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.canCreateUser", response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.error("Error checking permissions: ", response.getError()[0].message);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(canRegister);
        
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

I need to extend the visibility rule for this component to include a check on the `Account_Number__c` field, so that the component is only visible if the user has the necessary permissions ***and*** the `Account_Number__c` starts with "009".

This seems easy enough to do, but due to the asynchronicity of the queued actions, I'm not sure how best to do it. I would have preferred to keep the rendering logic in the client-side (`.js`) controller, something like this:

```
({
    //Controller function to intilizing the lightning component.
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.getUserDetails(component);
        helper.getAccountDetails(component, helper);    // stores Account details in some attribute "v.account"
        helper.getIsFrozen(component);
        helper.getEmail(component);
        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);

        var canRegister = component.get("c.canEnableExternalUser");

        canRegister.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var hasPermissionSet = response.getReturnValue();
                var hasValidAccounttNumber = component
                                                .get("v.account.Account_Number__c")     // accesses "v.account" attribute
                                                .match(/^001/g);

                component.set("v.canCreateUser", hasPermissionSet && hasValidAccounttNumber);
            } else {
                console.error("Error checking permissions: ", response.getError()[0].message);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(canRegister);

    },
    .
    .
    .
```

...where `getAccountDetails` is a helper that retrieves the required Account details (in this case, `Account_Number__c`) and stores it in a component attribute called `v.account`. But this won't work, as I'm attempting to access this attribute inside the `canCreateUser` action callback, which may return *before* `getAccountDetails`.

Alternatively, I could create a `hasValidAccountNumber` attribute on the component, whose value I set by calling a method like `hasValidAccountNumber` in the Apex controller, but it seems strange to put rendering logic in the server-side controller. And what if I needed to add another condition in the future?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure what the right approach would be in this case.

I think the first approach might be viable if I use promises, but I've never used them before and don't have much time to read up about them. What I like about the first approach is that it removes the need to store the required fields of the Account object in separate component attributes (as the original author has done with the "email" attribute).